# spark-dataframe/mongo - append data

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to append data to mongodb using spark-dataframe. For example, let's say there are 100k stocks in a portfolio:

Stock A

- Jan 2018

  - Profit: $30k

Stock B

- Jan 2018

  - Profile: -$10k

**MongoDB**:

```
_id: ObjectId('XXX1')

stock: Stock A

monthlyProfit: Array

    0: Object

        Month: Jan 2018

        Profit: 30k


_id: ObjectId('XXX2')

stock: Stock B

monthlyProfit: Array

    0: Object

        Month: Jan 2018

        Profit: -10k
```

If I were to append February profit, how do I add an element to an existing array and push it to mongodb without having a performance issue given same updates need to happen to all 100k documents in a collection?